# Using in_array on collections

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need to check for a name in an array of names but I having trouble passing an array instead of a collection to the in_array() method.

My blade code looks something like this

```
@foreach($ecn->areas as $area)
{{ $area->area }}:<br>
<ul>
    @foreach($area->people as $person)                              
        @if(in_array($person, $ecn->signatures->name ))
        <li><del>{{ $person }}</del></li>
        @else
        <li>{{ $person }}</li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endforeach
```

I know my problem is in the way im trying to access the list of signatures.

```
@if(in_array($person, $ecn->signatures->name ))
```

I can access them in another part of the page doing this

```
@foreach($ecn->signatures as $signature)
{{ $signature->name }}<br>
@endforeach
```

and everything is fine.

How can I access and pass the list of signatures as an array in this scenario?

Answer (score 23):

If you want to use `in_array()` version for Laravel Collections then you can use:

```
$collection->contains($needle)
```

It woks just like `in_array`.

If `$needle` is an integer, an `id` for example, don't forget to pluck first, like so:

```
$collection->pluck('id')->contains($needle)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `lists` or `pluck` method on the signatures collection to get a new collection of all the names. From there, you can either use the `contains()` method on the collection, or you can use the `all()` method to turn the collection into an array and use `in_array` directly.

I would suggest doing this outside of the foreach loop, so you're not generating this new collection and array every iteration.

Array:

```
// controller
$names = $ecn->signatures->lists('name')->all();

// blade
@if(in_array($person, $names))
```

Collection:

```
// controller
$names = $ecn->signatures->lists('name');

// blade
@if($names->contains($person))
```

You can also use `contains()` with a closure, which would let you get away with not creating an intermediate collection, but it's a little harder to read:

Contains with closure:

```
// blade
@if($ecn->signatures->contains(function ($key, $value) use ($person) {
    return $value->name == $person;
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Laravel Docs

> The `get` method returns an array of results where each result is an instance of the PHP `StdClass` object.

So you must convert your stdClass object to a array in your controller itself.

```
foreach ($ecn->signatures as $signature) 
     $nameArray[] = $signature->name;
```

and then you can use in_array in the blade template

```
@if(in_array($person, $nameArray))
```